# Populating UIPickerView with CoreData attribute -- Swift4 IOS11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, uipickerview

I have tried so much what I found here on StackOverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771243/populating-uipickerview-with-core-data-objects-using-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1), but nothing worked for me… I would like to use the Values from a Core Data Attribute for a PickerView.

My Entity is called "Task" with the Attribute "name".

I know I need to fetch the data and I already did that, but I don’t know how to just get the values of my Attribute as an Array.

At the moment I use A UIPickerView like this:

```
 var var1 = [""]
let var2 = ["---","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if(component==0){
        return var1[row]

    }
    return var2[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if(component==0){
        return var1.count
    }
    return var2.count
}
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 2
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if(component==0){
   test1 = var1[row]
    }
    test2 = var2[row]
}
```

This is how I fetch my Data for an UITableView:

```
//    GetData

func getData() {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())


    }
    catch{
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }
}
```

So I hope someone can help me, fetching the right attribute. I'm really new to Swift/Programming I started with swift 3 Days ago.. so a little code example would be great for me to understand how it works... Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** (How I populate the data in table view)

```
var tasks : [Task] = []

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = task.name


    return cell
}
```

**Update:**

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Task {

        return tasks[row]

}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
}
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
   test1 = tasks[row]

}
```

Comment: Show how you populate the data in your table view. Also deleting a question because it was down voted and reposting is frowned up.  Edit the original question with updates to improve it.

Comment: Updated my question. Yeah I'm sorry for that..

Comment: You have the answer right in front of you. How about changing out var1 for tasks?

Comment: if i use `return tasks[row]` in my picker it says --> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Task' to return type 'String?'

Comment: Ok I changed the return type to -> Task and i dont get errors but my PickerView just shows ? ? ?

Comment: Post the changes you have made.

Comment: Updated it, I also took out the second var for simplicity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159520/discussion-between-mwcsmac-and-sane).